# How do I make these values (of the HUE band) be in degrees (0° to 360°) and not in 0 to 255?

Tags: qgis

I converted an RGB image to HIS (i.rgb.his tool) in QGIS, however in the generated image attributes (HUE band), continual values from 0 to 255. Shouldn't they be from 0° to 360°?
How do I make these values (of the HUE band) be in degrees and not in 0 to 255?
[image]

Comment: 8-bit data only stores 256 values (0-255). You'd need to change to 16-bit or 32-bit float to get 0-360

Answer (score 1):

The Grass RGB image to HIS ([i.rgb.his](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass82/manuals/i.rgb.his.html)) tool outputs 0-255 by [dividing hue value by 360 then multiplying by 255](https://github.com/OSGeo/grass/blob/releasebranch_7_8/imagery/i.rgb.his/rgb2his.c#L120).

So to get 0-360 values, divide by 255 then multiply by 360 using the raster calculator, making sure you don't output to Byte output raster type:

[image]